# SQL Retrieving the last record in a sql query

Tags: mysql, database

I need to retrieve the last record in a mysql database table - is there a command for this?

Comment: What do you mean by last record? The one that was most recently inserted or the one that is last when ordering by a certain field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Last by what order?

```
SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY something (DESC) LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the row with the largest auto-incrementing id, you can do this.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```